Migrating Legacy VB6 App with C DLL to .NET MAUI – Where to Start? Cross-Platform Compatibility
I’m currently tasked with migrating a legacy sensor data acquisition application that was originally built using Visual Basic 6. It uses a C-based DLL to communicate with hardware and gather sensor data. The goal is to modernize the application and make it run across **multiple platforms—**Windows, iOS, macOS, and Android.
We’ve chosen .NET MAUI for this migration because of its cross-platform support. However, I have several questions and am a bit stuck on where to begin, especially regarding the DLL, which is obviously Windows-specific:
How do I get the existing C-based DLL to work on macOS, iOS, and Android?
Should the DLL be rewritten or is there a way to wrap it in a cross-platform solution?
If I need to rewrite or adapt the DLL, what approach should I take (e.g., P/Invoke, platform-specific services)?
How do I ensure hardware communication (which the DLL currently handles) will function across different platforms?
From where should I start this migration? What should be the first steps?
Are there any tools, libraries, or resources that can help with migrating the DLL or handling cross-platform hardware communication?
I’ve been searching online for answers but haven’t found a clear guide or process for this type of migration. Any guidance, resources, or advice would be extremely helpful!
Thank you!

This is too broad to be answered in SO's format.  And the core question really has nothing to do with MAUI.  I'd try re-writing it to be more narrow - ie, "how can I build a cross-platform library to read data from an XXXYYY device" and provide a lot more specific data about the "hardware" and "sensor" you're working with

We need more information: 1. What is the DLL? Is it a commercial tool with a name? Or, in-house/custom? 2. Is the DLL compiled as 16-bit, 32-bit, or 64-bit? 3. Do you have the source code for the DLL? 4. How is the computer connected to the hardware (e.g. RS-232, USB (what USB version (e.g. USB 2, 3, 4) and physical connectors (e.g. USB-A, USB-B, USB-C)))? 5. Is the wire protocol to the hardware documented?


Does the actual sensor data acquisition need to be cross-platform, or just the GUI? E.g. does the Android app need to talk directly to the hardware, or can there be an intermediary?



What is/are the hardware model(s)/specs? The best option really depends on these details. It will be most maintainable to replace the DLL. The best way to do this depends on how modern the hardware and protocol is (e.g. does it use USB standards?). If you can't feasibly replace the DLL (e.g. totally undocumented old serial protocol), you can try running the existing DLL in Wine. It probably won't be easy.


@MatthewFlaschen
Thank you for your detailed feedback. Here's the more detail


The DLL is an in-house/custom-built library that handles communication with the hardware sensors. It was developed specifically for this project many years ago.


The DLL is compiled as 32-bit.


Yes, I do have access to the source code for the DLL.
here https://github.com/Vaibhavpwrilink/Doc1.git


The computer is connected to the hardware via USB (Not Sure about the USB Version).


The protocol is partially documented, but it’s quite outdated and not in a modern standard format.





The sensor data acquisition itself needs to be cross-platform, as the app (on Android, macOS, iOS, and Windows) will need to communicate directly with the hardware.


The hardware is a proprietary sensor device. It communicates via USB using a custom protocol. Unfortunately, it doesn’t seem to follow modern USB standards.



@Jason I appreciate the suggestion to narrow down the scope. I understand that the original question was a bit broad, but I believe the core challenge is closely tied to the cross-platform nature of .NET MAUI, specifically regarding hardware comm.
I’m working on creating a cross-platform app that reads data from a custom sensor device, which is connected via USB using a custom protocol. I have access to the original DLL (32-bit, written in C for Windows), and my goal is to make this communication work across multiple OS.
Is there a way to adapt or wrap the existing DLL for non-Windows OS?

The source code you have linked is low-level code to talk to a very specific family of PCI Express chips. PCI Express does not exist on iOS and Android. So hardly anything in the source code will be helpful. Your first challenge is to figure out how you can communicate with the device on macOS, iOS and Android at all. Even if you can use USB communication and figure out the protocol, it won't work on iOS as Apple doesn't allow to talk to USB devices using custom protocols.

With the DLL source code, things are looking a lot brighter.  Hardware is not my area of expertise.  However, with this information, others should be able to help you.
There may be challenges getting custom hardware access with iOS (and maybe Android to a lesser extent), but again, others know more about these platforms.
There are cross-platform .NET USB libraries, including https://github.com/MelbourneDeveloper/Device.Net (this looks like the best place to start; on some platforms, it depends on LibUsbDotNet), https://github.com/LibUsbDotNet/LibUsbDotNet , and https://github.com/mikeobrien/HidLibrary .
If that doesn't work, you still have the option to write per-platform native hardware interface code, then interface it to the rest of the app (the non-hardware part can use .NET MAUI).
One thing I did notice: The source you provide mentions PCI a lot, but rarely USB.  It seems to expect to connect to a PCI card, not a USB device.  Again, though, I'm not a hardware expert.
As your first step, I would rebuild the DLL from source and make sure the VB6 program works properly with the just-built version.  This will help you verify that you have the real latest source code (if the DLL is not under active development).

I will explore the Libraries and let you know.
Thanks Appreciate your help.
